# Loosing the time in SetInterval in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have setInterval function where a timer will be running.

**Issue:**

For example if we have 2 menus, one is home and 2nd is timer(where our timer is running), if I stay in timer page, SetInterval timer is working fine, but if I visit home page, the timer is starting where I left the page.

**Requirement**:

Even if I visit the Home page, the timer should not stop, it should go continuesly.

**Code:**

```
    const pad = (val) => {
        return val > 9 ? val : '0' + val;
   };
   startTimer = () => {
       let timer = setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById(`seconds-${accountId}`)
                ? (document.getElementById(`seconds-${accountId}`).innerHTML = pad(++sec % 60))
                : null;
            document.getElementById(`minutes-${accountId}`)
                ? (document.getElementById(`minutes-${accountId}`).innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10)))
                : null;             
        }, 1000);
    }

 componentDidUpdate(){
     this.startTimer();
  }
```

Comment: add sample in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: You shouldn't be using DOM methods like `getElementById()` to update your UI. Instead, you should be using state and updating that to drive changes in your UI.

Comment: @NickParsons can you provide an example..?